# Xpath for following xml data:

Tags: xml, go, xpath

```
<root>  
  <measData>
    <measInfo measInfoId="OR.end">
      <granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2021-07-02T17:10:00+00:00"/>
      <measTypes>SgnbAddAttemptCell.enb.0 SgnbAddAttemptCell.enb.1 SgnbAddAttemptCell.enb.2 SgnbAddAttemptCell.enb.3</measTypes>
        <measResults>0 0 0 0</measResults>
</root>
```

What would be the xpath for measTypes portion in order to obtain each Name using a single line of code? Language i am using is - GO.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only XML code the XPath of measTypes will be simply

```
//measTypes
```

To get each name from the value (string) you can simply split the string by   (space)

Comment: Updated the question. Kindly have a look at it once again.

Comment: I see. What is the problem to split the string to get separate values? Also, please mention coding language you are using

Comment: The problem here is - i want to parse measTypes content as field with measResults as the respective values. Language is - GO

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xpath 2.0, you can [`tokenize`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) the output of xpath like:

```
//measTypes/tokenize(., '\s+')
```

Comment: The question has no details regarding the processor being used, but I believe this requires support for XPath 2.0+ in case anyone tries this and it doesn't work.

Comment: I am using - GO language.